# Protected access across package through reference variable in java

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

### [image]

For the above hierarchy, Below is the code from `pkg1`,

```
package ProtectedAccess.pkg1;

public class T {

    protected int f;
    protected void m(){

    }

}
```

---

Below is the code from `pkg2`, where  `test2` is tested by replacing `X` with class `T` or  `A` or `B` or `C` or `S` or `D` or  `E` or `F` or `G` or `H`.

```
package ProtectedAccess.pkg2;
import ProtectedAccess.pkg1.*;

class A extends T {}
class B extends T{}
class C extends B{}

public class S extends B{
    void test1(){
        f = 42;
        m();
    }

    void test2(X  t){
        t.f = 42;
        t.m();
    }

}

class D extends S{}
class G extends D{}
class E extends S{}
class H extends E{}
class F extends S{}
```

--

1)
If `X` is replaced with `T` or `A` or `B` or `C`, then compiler error.

2)
If `X` is replaced with `S` or `D` or `E` or `F` or `G` or `H`, then things code works fine.

How do I understand the working of two scenarios from aforementioned points? Please help!!!

Comment: it also does work for `class M extends S{}`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Did you go thru the question?

Comment: I did and Jon Skeet answers it very well in the linked duplicate. Read the bold part (from the JLS) of their answer very carefully.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  Do you mean, If you place `X` with `B` then one can send `new B()` object, then this is not access of protected members thru inhertiance? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer's bolded quote. _if and only if the type of `E` is `S` or a subclass of `S`_ In your field access, `t.f`, `t` would be of type `B` which is not `S` nor a subtype of `S`. It is therefore not allowed. This is all decided at compile time. The argument you pass to the method invocation is meaningless.